# onPressed multiple function did not work, trying to input data into firebase at the same time put out local push notification

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, flutter-local-notification, flutter-onpressed

I am 3 weeks into learning Flutter or any coding for that matter, essentially I want to create a section where the user key in their details into the firebase and upon clicking a button, it would put out a notification that their registration is completed, I tried a method that someone suggest using the {awaitxx, awaitxx} method, however, it did not work, the firebase works perfectly fine btw, anyone mind helping a rookie here?

```
 class VehicleRegNotification extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _VehicleRegNotificationState createState() => _VehicleRegNotificationState();
}

class _VehicleRegNotificationState extends State<VehicleRegNotification> {
  final notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    final settingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('icon v1.21024');
    final settingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) =>
            onSelectNotification(payload));


    notifications.initialize(
        InitializationSettings(settingsAndroid, settingsIOS),
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async =>
      await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage(payload: payload)),
      );

Padding(padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                  child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, left: 3),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[

                          SizedBox(height:20),
                          MaterialButton(
                            minWidth: double.infinity,
                            height: 60,
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await users.add({
                                'name' : name,
                                'id'   : id,
                                'num'  : num,
                                'vehicle' : vehicle });
                              Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StudentSection()));

                                  showOngoingNotification(notifications, title: 'Tite', body: 'Body');},

                            color: Color(0xff0095FF),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "Complete Registration",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  fontSize: 18
                              ),
                            ),

                          )

                        ],
                      )
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: First, call `showOngoingNotification`, then call `Navigator.pop()`.

Comment: wow, thanks, it works, appreciate it !!!!